# grepping of common lines between two file based on specific columns values in case of multi matching

Tags: sed, awk

I want to match column3 of file1 & column2 of file2 , after that i want to print all column of matching lines in a single line, i know how to do it but the problem is that if there are not  unique vales in column2 of file2 then output will be last matching line of file2. but i want that (conflicting) multi matching lines in seperate file & only matching unique line in output file.
example:-
I have two file like these:

`file1`

```
abc ram_1 ram1  
abc ram[0] ram0  
bcd raghu_reg_9 raghu9  
cde tanu/8 tanu8
```

`file2`

```
1 ram1  
2 thakur56  
3 ram0  
4 ram1  
5 ram2  
6 raghu9  
7 raghu
```

I tried awk as:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$0;next} { if ($3 in a){print a[$3],$1,$2}}' file2 file1
```

This gives output as:

```
4 ram1 abc ram_1  
3 ram0 abc ram[0]  
6 raghu9 bcd raghu_reg_9
```

But i want output1 as:

```
3 ram0 abc ram[0]  
6 raghu9 bcd raghu_reg_9
```

And in output2 as:

```
1 ram1 abc ram_1  
4 ram1 abc ram_1
```

because there are two entries for ram1 in column2 of file2 & when we match ram1 of column3 of file1 to the ram1 of column2 of file2 then this will match twice & will give 2nd ram1 as output, but i want that if this type of condition arise then these conflicting lines should go to seperate file so that i can manually decide which one should i choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join(1)` to combine the files into one row per matching key:

```
$ join -1 3 -2 2 -o 2.1,2.2,1.1,1.2 <(sort -k3,3 file1) <(sort -k2,2 file2)
6 raghu9 bcd raghu_reg_9
3 ram0 abc ram[0]
1 ram1 abc ram_1
4 ram1 abc ram_1
```

What this is doing is joining the two files on field 3 of file 1 (`-1 3`) and field 2 of file 2 (`-2 2`) outputting fields 1&2 of file 2 followed by fields 1&2 of file 1 (`-o 2.1,2.2,1.1,1.2`).

Join requires that each input file be sorted on the join fields, so `<(sort -k3,3 file1)` and `<(sort -k2,2 file2)` uses `bash(1)` "process substitution" to do concurrent input pipelines and feed it to the join command.

With that output, you can use `uniq(1)` to extract the unique and duplicate lines. Call the above command `joinit`, and you can do this:

```
$ joinit | uniq -u -f 1
6 raghu9 bcd raghu_reg_9
3 ram0 abc ram[0]
```

This prints out the unique lines (`-u`) after skipping the first field (`-f 1`).

```
$ joinit | uniq -D -f 1
1 ram1 abc ram_1
4 ram1 abc ram_1
```

This prints out all the duplicated lines (`-D`) after skipping the first field (`-f 1`).

To tie that all together and put your output in `output1` and `output2`, you can use `tee(1)` to feed the `joinit` pipeline through two separate filters:

```
$ join -1 3 -2 2 -o 2.1,2.2,1.1,1.2 <(sort -k3,3 file1) <(sort -k2,2 file2) \
  | tee >(uniq -u -f 1 > output1) | uniq -D -f 1 > output2
```

Again, this takes advantage of `bash(1)` "process substitution" to have concurrent output pipelines feeding each to a different `uniq` command.

Comment: thanks for reply. i ran it ,but  it gives "Missing name for redirect."

Comment: I am able to run these commands separately but not concurrently.Please help me to run concurrently. BTW it solved me problem . thanks :)

Comment: Please add another output file output3 with remaining unmatched line of file1 means with line "cde tanu/8 tanu8" .

Comment: @yogendrasingh: I have used bash features in this answer. If you are not using bash, you will need to do it as separate steps.